# Python 3 - Unable to install 'Crypt' module successfully

Tags: python-3.x, crypt

I am unable to download and install 'crypt' module.
I am using Windows10 OS and Python version being - Python 3.6.1

## I tried the following-

```
C:\>py -m pip install crypt  
Collecting crypt  
  Using cached crypt-1.4.1.tar.gz  
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:  
    Traceback (most recent call last):  
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>  
      File "C:\Users\User01\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_mkl3ie0\crypt  \setup.py", line 582  
        s.connect((base64.b64decode(rip), 017620))  
                                               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid token  

    ----------------------------------------  
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users  \User01\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_mkl3ie0\crypt\
```

I have the following modules installed.

```
C:\>py -m pip list --format=columns

Package         Version  

certifi --        2017.4.17  
chardet --        3.0.3  
crypto  --        1.4.1  
ez-setup --       0.9  
idna --           2.5  
Naked --          0.1.31  
nmap --           0.0.1  
pip --            9.0.1  
python-nmap --    0.6.1  
PyYAML --         3.12  
requests --       2.17.3  
setuptools --     36.0.1  
shellescape --    3.4.1  
urllib3 --        1.21.1
```

Any pointers to my issue will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your list says the module is installed. The error you are getting is because for whatever reason, python 2 code is being run under python 3. You should check whether the module is compatible with python 3, that you are running the version of python you think you are running, etc.

Comment: Thanks pvg ... Just a clarification, From the list, I have crypto installed but not crypt. Is crypto same as crypt in Python 3 ?

Comment: It's not really clear what 'crypt' is supposed to be. I don't see a 'crypt' in pypi and what I do see from what you've posted is that you're attempting to install 'crypto'. Do you have a link to the package you're trying to install?